# idangero.us Dynamically create and remove slides with Thumbs Gallery With Two-way Control

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, swiper.js

I am using Swiper to dynamically append and prepend slides on SlideEndChange but after appending a new slide, the activeSlide jumps back to the start.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var noOfPages = 7;
var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
    spaceBetween: 10,
    effect: 'slide',
    onSlideChangeEnd: function(swiper){updateReadingPages(swiper);}
});
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
    spaceBetween: 10,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    touchRatio: 0.2,
    slideToClickedSlide: true

});
galleryTop.params.control = galleryThumbs;
galleryThumbs.params.control = galleryTop;


    var startPage = 1;
    var endPage = 5;

   if(noOfPages > 5){
       endPage = 5;
   }else{
      endPage = noOfPages;
   }

    var i = 1;
    for(i;i<=5;i++){
        initLoaded(i,"append");
    }
    var swipeLeftForFirstTime = false;//To prevent slideTo(activeIndexTwo) form setting previousIndex at the first time after reaching End of Pages....
function updateReadingPages() {
    if (galleryTop.activeIndex > galleryTop.previousIndex) { //Swipe Right
        if (galleryTop.activeIndex >= 3) {
            //If activeSlide is fourth slide, append a new slide and remove slide at index [0].
            if (endPage <noOfPages) {
                endPage++;
                startPage++;
                //alert("swipeRight And endPage = " + startPage + "and" +endPage);
                initLoaded(endPage,"append");
                var activeIndexOne = galleryTop.activeIndex;
                galleryTop.removeSlide(0);
                galleryThumbs.removeSlide(0);
                galleryTop.slideTo(activeIndexOne, 0, false);
            }else{
                swipeLeftForFirstTime = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        //Swipe Left
        if (galleryTop.activeIndex <= 2) {
            //alert("swipeLeft And startPage = " + startPage);
            if (startPage > 1) {
                endPage--;
                startPage--;
                initLoaded(startPage,"prepend");
                var activeIndexTwo = galleryTop.activeIndex;
                galleryTop.removeSlide(5);
                galleryThumbs.removeSlide(5);

                if(swipeLeftForFirstTime){
                    galleryTop.slideTo(activeIndexTwo, 0, false);
                }else{
                    galleryTop.slideTo(activeIndexTwo-1, 0, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function initLoaded(number,option){

    if(option === "append"){
        galleryTop.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide" width="100%"; height="300px">'+number+'</div>');
    }else{
       galleryTop.prependSlide('<div class="swiper-slide" width="100%"; height="100px">'+number+'</div>');
    }

   if(option === "append"){
      galleryThumbs.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Thumb '+number+'</div>');
   }else{

     galleryThumbs.prependSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Thumb '+number+'</div>');
}
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PHYO/985c90ks/10/)

Edit: Add working function and example on JSFiddle... Thanks to Rafael Lepkoski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following code snippet inside `function initLoaded`

```
 if (option === "append") {
    galleryTop.slideTo(number)
 }
```

Like this:

```
function initLoaded(number,option) {
    if (option === "append") {
        galleryTop.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide" width="100%"; height="300px">'+number+'</div>');
        galleryThumbs.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Thumb '+number+'</div>');
        galleryTop.slideTo(number - 1);
    } else {
        galleryTop.prependSlide('<div class="swiper-slide" width="100%"; height="100px">'+number+'</div>');
        galleryThumbs.prependSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Thumb '+number+'</div>');
    }
}
```

You could also get the active index before appending and use it afterwards to slide back to that index:

```
var activeIndex = galleryTop.activeIndex;
galleryTop.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide" width="100%"; height="300px">'+number+'</div>');
galleryTop.slideTo(activeIndex);
```

**Edit:**

You should use `var activeIndex = galleryTop.activeIndex;` before adding and removing slides and after that you should call `mySwiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks);`.

```
var activeIndex = galleryTop.activeIndex;
galleryTop.removeSlide(0);
galleryThumbs.removeSlide(0);
galleryTop.slideTo(activeIndex, 0, false);


var activeIndex = galleryTop.activeIndex;
galleryTop.removeLastSlide();
galleryThumbs.removeLastSlide();
galleryTop.slideTo(activeIndex, 0, false);
```

So your `function updateReadingPages` should look like this:

```
function updateReadingPages(swiper) {
   if (swiper.activeIndex > swiper.previousIndex) { //Swipe Right
       if (swiper.activeIndex == 3) {
           //If activeSlide is fourth slide, append a new slide and remove slide at index [0].    
           if (endPage < noOfPages) {
               endPage++;
               startPage++;
               //alert("swipeRight And endPage = " + startPage + "and" +endPage);
               initLoaded(endPage,"append");
               var activeIndex = galleryTop.activeIndex;
               galleryTop.removeSlide(0);
               galleryThumbs.removeSlide(0);
               galleryTop.slideTo(activeIndex, 0, false);
           }
       }
   } else {
       //Swipe Left
       if (swiper.activeIndex == 2) {
           //alert("swipeLeft And startPage = " + startPage);
           if (startPage > 1) {
               endPage--;
               startPage--;
               initLoaded(startPage-1,"prepend");
               var activeIndex = galleryTop.activeIndex;
               galleryTop.removeLastSlide();
               galleryThumbs.removeLastSlide();
               galleryTop.slideTo(activeIndex, 0, false);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rafael but it doesn't work properly. I have tried all your suggestions. I think two ways control is a problem. I will try using'onReachBeginning and onReachEnd'.

Comment: Can you explain what is the exact behaviour that you are expecting? I couldn't figure it out properly.

Comment: slideTo(2) is working fine for galleryTop but galleryThumbs's index is always [0]. After appending and swipe to next slide, the slider starts from index [0] again, i.e. it should be swiped to index [3] but instead swiped to index [1]. And I also try using slideTo(activeIndex), it duplicates slides. I tried galleryThumbs.slideTo(number) and (activeIndex) but it does't work.

Comment: I want to keep 5 slides only. If I swipe --> append new slide at the end and delete one at [0]. If I swipe <-- prepend a new slide at the start and delete the last one.

Comment: Alright, now it's better. I'm gonna take a look again :)

Comment: Works great, thanks. I will edit if statement. It was my fault, not yours. I should have used "if (swiper.activeIndex >= 3)" and "if (swiper.activeIndex <= 2)".